# Gnuplot doesn't plot the errorfunction

Tags: function, gnuplot

Hello my dear friends,

For another assignment I need to plot a diagram with an errorfunction.
It should be quite easy, but I still have difficulties with it.
For example I need to plot the following function:

`(1/2)*(1-erf(x/(sqrt(4*4*10**(-10)))))`

But gnuplot shows me only a line at y=0. It doesn't matter what I'm using in the argument of the errorfunction. The value is always 0. 
Do I need another package or other arguments to use the errorfunction?

Best regards,

Hodor

Comment: Gnuplot uses integer division, use `(1.0/2.0) * ...`

Comment: Thanks. I got it!